# Python Flask request object doesn't contain data until I access it

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with a small Python server written with Flask, and I'm seeing some very weird behavior with HTTP request objects.

When I receive a request, I immediately attempt to log `request.__dict__`. However, upon retrieving my logs, I noticed that `request.__dict__` does not contain the actual body of the request (it should be in `request.data`).

I then decided to log `request.data`, and instead of None like I was expecting, since I didn't see it in `request.__dict__`, I saw the contents of the request body.

Even more interestingly, as soon as I placed the `request.data` line above the `request.__dict__` line, the output from logging `request.__dict__` also contained the data property.

It's almost like `request.data` does not exist until I attempt to access it for the first time. Is this some weird behavior with Flask's request object? Are there any other properties that behave like this? What's the best practice for making sure the request object is fully "loaded"?

Answer (score 5):

Flask's (actually Werkzeug's) Request class doesn't have a `data` attribute to start with: it has a data method wrapped with the [`@cached_property`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/utils.py#L35) decorator. As you can see from the implementation of that decorator, when the property is first accessed, it creates an entry in `__dict__` to contain the value returned by the function, which has the effect of avoiding the need to recalculate it each time - basically, a form of memoization.

Although the implementation is very clever (as you'd expect from Armin), there's nothing particularly surprising about the effect - there are plenty of ways that an attribute would not be found in `__dict__`.

Comment: Additionally, what you get in a Flask view seems to be a [`LocalProxy`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py#L250) object that has [`__slots__`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py#L285) defined and proxies [`__dict__`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py#L304) and other attributes to the actual object.